# Django icalendar dtstart datetime issue

Tags: python, django, icalendar

I have a form in Django-python for an event program. I'm trying to create an ics file for the events with icalendar, for this, I want to get the values 'dtstart' and 'dtend' from the variables 'starttime' and 'endtime' in the form, but I'm getting the code: Wrong datetime format. Anyone with any advice to solve this issue?

ERROR

```
            elif not ical[15:]:
                return datetime(*timetuple)
            elif ical[15:16] == 'Z':
                return pytz.utc.localize(datetime(*timetuple))
            else:
                raise ValueError(ical)
        except:
            raise ValueError('Wrong datetime format: %s' % ical) …
class vDuration(object):
    """Subclass of timedelta that renders itself in the iCalendar DURATION
    format.
    """
```

CODE

```
def event(request, id=None):
    instance = Event_cal()
    
    if id:
        instance = get_object_or_404(Event_cal, pk=id)
    else:
        instance = Event_cal()

    form = EventForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        
        startdate = request.POST.get('starttime')
        endate = request.POST.get('endtime')

        event = Event()
        event.add('summary', 'My Summary')
        event.add('dtstart', vDatetime.from_ical(startdate))
        event.add('dtend', vDatetime.from_ical(endate))
```

Thanks in advance, I am learning python, so I don't have have much experience.

Comment: Please post the actual error.

Comment: The actual error is as follow: 

ValueError at /event
Wrong datetime format: 2020-10-07T22:28
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/event
Django Version: 3.1.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
Wrong datetime format: 2020-10-07T22:28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reformat the date times into one of the RFC5545 formats.    Please see the RFC5545 specifications instructions for the datetime formats: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5.

There are 3 accepted datetime formats:

1. Local or 'floating' eg: 19980118T230000
2. Date with UTC time eg:  19980119T070000Z and
3. Date with local time and timezone reference eg:
   TZID=America/New_York:19980119T020000

Comment: Thanks, @anmari, with your suggestion I solved the issue.
 I did the following:

1. I applied datetime.strptime to my current datetime
        startdate = datetime.strptime(startdate, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")


2. I formated the field with one of the RFC5545 formats
        startdate = startdate.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")